Kafka сжатие сообщений при cleanup.policy=compact
Может кто-то сталкивался - есть топик кафка с "вечным" хранением событий cleanup.policy=compact
Существует множество потребителей и договориться о том, что события будут сжаты не получится. Но хотелось бы оптимизировать дисковое пространство.
Сталкивался с информацией, что возможно сжатие на стороне брокера. Причем новые события которые хранятся, к примеру, неделю будут не сжаты(брокер присылает без сжатия). А вот события, которые "вечно" хранятся будут сжаты.
Существует ли такой механизм? Если да, то дайте направление - что это за настройки. И как будут в этом случае потребители вычитывать старые события?

UPD - нашел информацию, что при указании compact изначально всё работает как мне и надо. Но вопрос тогда со степенью сжатия? Где найти такую информацию, чтобы примерно прикинуть место на диске.

Так то Кафка по дефолту очень затратная по ресурсам штука. Для тех, кто не ограничен в материальных ресурсах и хочет гонять миллионы сообщений в секунду. Но это лирика. Может саму файловую систему использовать сжатую? Хотя это может тормозить работу Кафки, наверное.
